# Sort HashMap keys and store in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I need to do the task of sorting `HashMap` keys which will be String always and store them in an `ArrayList`. I have written below piece of code

```
public static List<String> getSortedListByKeys(HashMap<String,String> keysDictionary)
    {        
        List<String> sortedKeysList = null;
        SortedSet<String> sortedKeysSet = null;

        if(keysDictionary == null || keysDictionary.size() == 0){
            return null;
        }

        sortedKeysSet = new TreeSet<>(keysDictionary.keySet());
        sortedKeysList = new ArrayList<>(sortedKeysSet);

        return sortedKeysList;
    }
```

I have run it and it is working fine.

Just want to know if there is any better way to achieve the same

Comment: instead of returnung null, it's better to return empty list via Collections.emptyList().

Comment: Not wrong, but I would probably just put the keys in the `ArrayList` and sort it with `Collections.sort`.

Comment: It kind of depends if you strive to achieve the best possible time or space complexity. Your solution is fine if you do not care that much about the latter. Otherwise as Pietu1998 suggested - just  sort an `ArrayList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to sort the Strings based on natural ordering itself, you directly create a list and use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) on it.

```
sortedKeysList = new ArrayList<>(keysDictionary.keySet());
Collections.sort(sortedKeysList);
```

This way you can avoid using a `SortedSet` as an intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should definitely consider to use a TreeMap, insertion and retrieval will be be a little bit slower (O(log(N) instead of O(1)) but you will have key already sorted in the right order.

The Java doc of TreeMap : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 you could do it quite easily with the following:

```
Map<String, String> keysDictionary = new HashMap<>();
List<String> sortedKeys = keysDictionary.keySet().stream()
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With this you:

1. Obtain the key set, being a `Set<String>`.
2. Wrap it to a `Stream<String>`.
3. Sort it, via `sorted()`.
4. Collect it into a `List<Stream>` supplied by `Collectors.toList()`, this will be an `ArrayList<String>` as no additional constraints have been specified.

It might be more burden than it would be in Java 7, but I would say it is about equal once you know the `Stream`s API, it gets more fun when you put additional constraints. And then the real profit shows.